# clear button in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar

Hi can I remove clear button (X button)present in UISearchBar?

I didn't find any delegate for that. There is one for cancel button.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not directly access the *clearButton* of *UISearchBar*. You have to loop through the subviews of the *UISearchBar* to find the *UITextField*, and set its *clearButtonMode* property to *UITextFieldViewModeNever*.

*Note: This is not a permanent solution because this may not work in future if the implementation of UISearchBar changes by the subsequent iOS updates*.

Comment: for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews)
 {
  if ([subview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
  {
   [(UITextField *)subview setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the textField of the Search Bar

```
UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

use in - searchBarTextDidBeginEditing method.

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
 {

UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;


 }
```